# Stata plotting histograms next to each other

Tags: histogram, stata

I want to plot a histogram showing how many judges graduated from each law school, by judge's birth cohort.

I am using:

```
twoway (histogram j_lawschool_num if j_cohort_num == 1 | j_cohort_num == 2, color(red%30)) ///        
       (histogram j_lawschool_num if j_cohort_num == 3 | j_cohort_num == 4, color(green%30)), ///   
       legend(order(1 "Judges Born Before 1959" 2 "Judges After 1959" )) xlabel(1/6,valuelabel alternate) ///
       xtitle(Law School Category) ytitle(Density) graphregion(color(white) margin(large)) bgcolor(white)
```

But the bars are on top of each other. How can I make them next to each other so there is no overlap of bars in the same law school category?

Currently it looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is a case for -graph bar-.

Comment: Hmm I tried `graph bar j_lawschool_num, over(j_senior)` but it only gave me one set of bars. I grouped judge cohorts into two to define j_senior.

Comment: Indeed. One response, one grouping variable => one set of bars. My best guess is that you may need two `over()` options. But: no example data here, so your code is not reproducible, and the code in your comment includes a different variable from that in your question, so this isn't clear to me. Your best strategy is possibly to post some real or realistic data, or to use a dataset downloadable by all users into  Stata and give an analogue of what you want, e.g. after `sysuse auto, clear` or `webuse nlswork, clear`.